# How to handle Timeout Exception by the asyncio task itself just before asyncio raise TimeoutError

Tags: python, python-3.x, async-await, python-asyncio, coroutine

Due to one use case, One of my long-running functions executes multiple instructions. But I have to give a maximum time for its execution. If the function is not able to finish its execution within the allocated time, it should clean up the progress and return.

Let's have a look at a sample code below:

```
import asyncio

async def eternity():
    # Sleep for one hour
    try:
        await asyncio.sleep(3600)
        print('yay!, everything is done..')
    except Exception as e:
        print("I have to clean up lot of thing in case of Exception or not able to finish by the allocated time")


async def main():
    try:
        ref = await asyncio.wait_for(eternity(), timeout=5)
    except asyncio.exceptions.TimeoutError:
        print('timeout!')

asyncio.run(main())
```

The function `eternity` is the long-running function. The catch is that, in case of some exception or reaching the maximum allocated time, the function needs to clean up the mess it has made.

P.S. `eternity` is an independent function and only it can understand what to clean.

I am looking for a way to raise an exception inside my task just before the timeout, OR send some interrupt or terminate signal to the task and handle it.
Basically, I want to execute some peice of code in my task before asyncio raises the `TimeoutError` and take control.
Also, I am using Python 3.9.
Hope I was able to explain the problem.

Comment: I think you already have it.  The asyncio.wait_for method cancels the Task in the event of a timeout.  If you catch an `asyncio.CancelledError` inside `eternity`, you can do the clean-up there.  Note that `asyncio.CancelledError` inherits from BaseException and will not be caught by your existing `except Exception` block.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is async context manager:

```
import asyncio

class MyClass(object):

    async def eternity(self):
        # Sleep for one hour
        await asyncio.sleep(3600)
        print('yay!, everything is done..')

    async def __aenter__(self):
        return self

    async def __aexit__(self, exc_type, exc, tb):
        print("I have to clean up lot of thing in case of Exception or not able to finish by the allocated time")


async def main():
    try:
        async with MyClass() as my_class:
            ref = await asyncio.wait_for(my_class.eternity(), timeout=5)
    except asyncio.exceptions.TimeoutError:
        print('timeout!')


asyncio.run(main())
```

And this is the output:

```
I have to clean up lot of thing in case of Exception or not able to finish by the allocated time
timeout!
```

For more details take a look at [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#asynchronous-context-managers).